# Showing a measure is transformation invariant as in the proof of Krylov Bogolubov

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

First, context: Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and $C(X)$ the set of continuous functions on $X$ equipped with the sup norm. Let $T:X\to X$ continuous. Fix $x \in X$. Then one can show that $S_f^n(x) =\displaystyle \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(T^k(x))$ is a bounded linear functional on $C(X)$, which has a convergent subsequence for all $g\in C(X)$. Denote the limit to be $S_g^\infty(x)$. This gives rise to the linear functional $L_x(g) = S_g^\infty(x)$, which is positive, so by Riesz Representation Theorem, we have $L_x(g) = \int_X gd\mu$ for some Borel probability measure.

Now we are basically at my question. The author of the book I'm using (Dynamical Systems by Brin & Stuck) next shows that $S_g^\infty (x) = S_g^\infty (Tx)$ to conclude that $\mu$ is $T$-invariant. However, I don't know why this is.

If we could work with characteristic functions, we would have the following:

$\mu(A) = \int_X {\mathcal{X}}_A d\mu = L_x(\mathcal{X}_A)= L_x(\mathcal{X}_A\circ T) = \int_X \mathcal{X}_A \circ T d\mu = \mu(T^{-1}(A)).$

However, we've been working with continuous functions. It is not true, I don't think, that we can approximate simple functions by continuous functions in the sup norm. So I'm quite confused about how we get that $\mu$ is $T-$invariant. Moreover, I'm not sure I get why $T$ being continuous is necessary.

For more context, here is the statement of the the theorem.

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and
$T: X → X$ a continuous map. Then there is a $T$-invariant Borel probability
measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Comment: So he has shown that there exist a positive linear functional $L$ and its corresponding measure $\mu$, with the property that $L(f)=\int f d\mu = L(f\circ T) = \int f\circ T d\mu$, for every $f\in C(X)$. If you define a measure $\nu$ as $\nu(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$, then by the Change of Variables Theorem (eg. Aliprantis - Infinite Dimensional Analysis, pg. 484-485), you have that $\int fd\nu=\int f\circ T d\mu$, for every $f \in C(X)$, so the two measures are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from looking at the averages that $$S^\infty_g(Tx)=\int_X(g\circ T)\,d\mu.$$ So $$\int_X g\,d\mu=\int_X(g\circ T)\,d\mu$$ for all $g$ continuous. Since continuous functions are dense in $L^1(X,\mu)$ (or apply Lusin theorem and then Tietze theorem), you can simply replace $g$ by a characteristic function.

Comment: I ended up using the canonical function for Urysohn's Lemma in metric spaces, but I think this would've worked well too. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I just noticed a mistake in my proof. However, I think the same problem pops up, unless I am mistaken, in yours. Let's say our continuous function $g$ approximates our characteristic function $\mathcal{X}_A$ very well. Then I don't see how we can make $\int g \circ T d\mu$ approximate $\int \mathcal{X}_A \circ T d\mu$ without already assuming T measure preserving.

Comment: Oh lord. I finally got it, from noting that $\int f dT_*\mu = \int f\circ T d\mu$ for all measurable $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Maniulating the finite version of the equality of interest into a difference and expanding the definitions yields much cancellation.  (The sequence of points you evaluate at in one expression is almost the same as in the other, except for one endpoint of each.)
\begin{align*}
S_g^{n}(Tx) - S_g^{n}(x) &= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(T^k Tx) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(T^k x) \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(T^{k+1} x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(T^k x) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} g(T^k x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(T^k x) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( g(T^n x) - g(T^0 x) \right)
\end{align*}
Since $g$ is bounded, the expression in parentheses is bounded, so in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, this last expression is zero.

Comment: No, I understood that part. I get that $S_g^\infty(x) = S_g^\infty (Tx)$. I don't understand why this says $T$ is measure preserving, however.

Comment: You write "Let $T:X \rightarrow X$ continuous measure preserving."  As given, $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and $T$ is ($X$-)measure preserving.  Alternatively, by the definitions, $\int_{x \in X} g(Tx) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x) = L_{Tx}(g) = S_g^\infty(Tx) = S_g^\infty(x) = L_x(g) = \int_{x \in X} g(x) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$.

Comment: Wow, I'm so sorry. I didn't mean to take it to be measure preserving. Apologies! 

Of course that wouldn't really make sense before we have a measure, anyways.

Comment: Once I had your comment, I was led to question what you had written about $T$, so wrote the "Alternatively, ...".  I'm just glad you seem to have your question settled.